# Cannot call the method save of undefined. Mongojs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I have a simple method as follows to write to a mongodb database.  It uses the Mongojs module.  Everything seems fine with the exception of the last line.  I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined" in the console.  What could the problem be?

```
var db = require('mongojs').connect('mongodb://foo:bar@something.com:10027/foobar');

var saveImage = function(file, usr) {

    var imagesCollection = db.collection('Images');
    var Image = {};
    Image.imageFileName = file;
    Image.user = usr;
    Image.date = new Date();
    db.imagesCollection.save(Image);

}

exports.saveImage = saveImage;
```

Comment: Try to change `db.imagesCollection.save(Image)` to `imagesCollection.save(Image)`.

Comment: @alFReDNSH Yes, that was the issue.  Thanks!  I can't believe I missed that.  If you submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `db.imagesCollection.save(Image)` to `imagesCollection.save(Image)`.

`"TypeError: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined"` means on that line something that has a method of `save` is undefined. Next try to `console.log` some variables to understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that db is an object and does not contain a definition of imagesCollection.

db.imagesCollection.save(Image);

add debugger right above
db.imagesCollection.save(Image);

and you'll be able to see that imagesCollection is not currently a property of db.